# shift the music

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Spare a thought for musicians. Dozens of albums have been pulled from release during the pandemic, with artists unable to tour, properly promote and **shift new music**. As sales plummet, casualties have included hotly anticipated comeback albums from the Dixie Chicks and Alanis Morissette. But Charli XCX, a 27-year-old British singer, has taken a different tack. “How I’m Feeling Now”, her fourth album, was released yesterday. It was created entirely from scratch at the artist’s home as she self-isolates. Taking less than two months to produce, it’s the first album shaped by the covid-19 age. The singer has documented the process on Instagram Live and used regular Zoom calls to invite fans’ contributions and feedback. Charli XCX’s distinctive beat-heavy electro-pop has already earned her two previous Grammy nominations. And early reviews of this latest effort have given it a resounding thumbs-up. Pop music’s “reigning futurist” appears to be living up to her image.

--
with the original meaning of change/move, what does "shift" mean here?

Comment: By claiming that **shift** is using "the original meaning of change/move," you've already answered your own question. The merchandise (music) cannot be moved from where it's made to the hands of customers. In other words, it cannot be sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shift) has for **shift**

> **1.8** *informal* Sell (something).
>   *a lot of high-priced product you simply don't know how to shift*.

So the meaning is closer to your **move** than to **change**. The passage goes directly on to

> As sales plummet...

The main point is that without live appearances to promote their work, sales are suffering.

Answer (score 0):

Metaphorically, the music is moving from the sellers to the buyers -- except that it isn't.